# Why is npm installing a lower version (according to my package-lock.json) than what is specified in my package.json?

Tags: json, npm, package.json, npm-scripts, package-lock.json

After deleting my `package-lock.json`, and the node modules folder, and running an npm install on my project, I noticed that it is installing a lower version of `@babel/core` than what is specified in my `package.json`. It seems to be installing `7.17.12` when it should be installing `7.17.5` (you can see the difference between the previous `package-lock.json`):

[image]

My `package.json` specifies `@babel/core` should be at least **7.17.5**:

[image]

The weird part is, when I go into my node modules folder after this has happened, and check on `@babel/core`'s package.json I can see that it has in fact installed the `7.17.12` version. However, it has a `_from` field that states `7.17.5`:
[image]

Comment: This only happens, when deleting my package-lock.json and then doing an npm install. If I keep my package-lock and run npm install, this doesn't happen.

Comment: I cannot see what the issue is here because what’s happening seems to be as expected. If I use the [semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/) and enter `@babel/core` in the _"pick a package"_ field, then enter `~7.17.5` (as per your _package.json_) in the _"enter a range"_ field it shows that it resolves to version  `7.17.12`.

Comment: Okay, so I suppose its acting as expected then. I assumed it would've atleast gotten version 7.17.5